# custom Extention with multiple RTE (text) but different configuration

Tags: typo3, rte, tca

in tables.sql i define

teaser text,
highlights text,
description text,
producttable text,

in TCA I configure this:

```
    'teaser' => [
        'l10n_mode' => 'prefixLangTitle',
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'teaser',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'enableRichtext' => true,
                'richtextConfiguration' => 'myDefaultConfig',
                'fieldControl' => [
                    'fullScreenRichtext' => [
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                ],
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim',
            ],
    ],
```

For highlights, description, producttable I simply copy this lines and change name/label.
In BE all is fine, except the RTE configuration is correct only for the first field (teaser -> 'richtextConfiguration' => 'myDefaultConfig'), all following fields show the minimal configuration from EXT:rte_ckeditor

I user typo3 V10.40 - any ideas?

Comment: This should normally work as you expected. And if you have really only exchanged name/label, I can't think of... Do you want to copy the configuration of all 3 fields into your post? Maybe there's something that is different, and more eyes see more.